# Binding image to data

Tags: xaml

I have a list of products, and I want them to have diferents images, how do I bind an image so that each of my products in the list have a diferent image?

```
    <PivotItem Header="Lista">
        <ListView x:Name="List1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ProdutoViewModel.Produtos}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="list:Produto">
                    <ListView>
                   <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Nome, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="100,10,10,10"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Preco, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="100,10,10,10"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Disponivel, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="100,10,10,10"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Fornecedor, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="100,10,10,10"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Categoria, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="100,10,10,10"/>
                        <Image Source="Assets/mouse.png" Height="50" Width="80" Margin="10,-300,100,10"/>
                        <Image Source="Assets/teclado.png" Height="50" Width="80" Margin="10,-100,100,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: the code above, adds those two images each time that I add a product, so every product have those two images.

Comment: The images should be part of your view model, as the other properties. Then you can bind the Image.Source property just like the TextBlock.Text property. The type of the view model properties could either be string or Uri for an image path, or ImageSource.